# Defining and replacing variable based on input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, replace

I am attempting to replace the `input` variable with user submitted channel name from the form input each time a new value is entered. So far, this just seems to break and not displaying anything. Any advice is very appreciated!

```
<div style="padding-left: 16px">
<form id="form" onsubmit="channelChanger()">
Channel: <input id="a" type="text">
<button type="submit" value="Submit" >Submit</button>
</form>

<div align="center" width="100%" id="twitch-embed"></div>
<script src="https://embed.twitch.tv/embed/v1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var input;
function channelChanger() {
  var input = document.getElementById('a').value;

  var embed = new Twitch.Embed("twitch-embed", {
        width: 1280,
        height: 720,
        channel: input
      });
      return embed;}
</script>
</div>
```

**UPDATED - onclick typo fixed and changed second input to button did not change the result. Also, added return function. Still unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your 'onClick' prop. I also would have expected the element with the typo to be a button rather than a second input.

If you change those two things, what happens?

Comment: Still no luck, the page remains unresponsive.